# Remove specific criteria from Varien_Db_Select join

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.1.0, varien, select

I have `Varien_Db_Select` object with some joins and I need to change condition in one of them. How can I do this?

update: I found that condition in "from" part and then in "joinCondition" part. I can loop through, but I can't put them back

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So this is what I came up with:

```
$fromAndJoins = $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::FROM);
foreach($fromAndJoins as $key=>$joins){
        if(strpos($joins['joinCondition'],$attribute->getAttributeCode().'_idx.attribute_id')!==false){
            $newcondition = //change $joins['joinCondition'] as you want
            $fromAndJoins[$key]['joinCondition']=$newcondition;

        }
    }
$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::FROM);
$select->setPart(Zend_Db_Select::FROM,$fromAndJoins);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the method I would use.

You can get the conditions ("where" part) like this:

```
$where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart('where');
```

Then you can loop through the conditions like this:

```
foreach ($where as $key => $condition)
{
// Do what you need
}
```

Finally once you've made the changes you needed, don't forget to apply the updated condition to your colllection:

```
$collection->getSelect()->setPart('where', $where);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error

> You cannot define a correlation name 'xxx' more than once

you have to `unset($fromAndJoins[$key]);` item, where the key was in my case

```
$key = $attribute->getAttributeCode().'_idx.attribute_id';
```